# MVC Data Annotation RequiredIf Is being Ignored?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I have a Conditional Required field. If a check box is Checked than the field is required. However it appears as though it is just ignoring the RequiredIf Data Annotation. 
here is the View Model that encapulates the Object with the information that I'm looking for.

```
 public class CreateEditVm
{
    public CCObject { get; set; }
    //Properties Omitted for clearity Left out
}
public class CCObject 
{
     public bool IsActive{ get; set; } ;

     [Display(Name = "Property Should be Optional")]
     [RequiredIf("IsActive", Comparison.IsEqualTo, true)]
     public int? OptionalPropertyId { get; set; }
public List<OptionlPropertyList> {get;set;}

}
```

This is the view that posts the Model Back. But as I toggle the IsActive Flag on and off it never looks at the RequiredIf Annotation.   I've tested that I can get it go do a required by removing the Nullable ? from the Optional Property.

```
@model Core.ViewModels.CreateEditVm


@using (Ajax.BeginForm("CreateEdit", "MapCompanyCenterPortfolioGroup", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "AddResults", HttpMethod = "POST", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, LoadingElementId = "loader" }))
{

    <div id="AddResults"></div>


    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">

        <div class="form-group row">
OptionalProperty
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Object.OptionalPropertyId, new SelectList(Model.OptionalPropertyList, "Id", "DisplayName"), "Please Select", new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Object.OptionalPropertyId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                <div>  <small class="text-muted">If "Is In Recon" is Checked, this is Required.</small></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-md-2">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="form-check col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Object.IsActive, new { @class = "form-check-label", type = "checkbox" })
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Object.IsActive, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-check-label" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Object.IsActive, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>



         @{ Html.RenderPartial("_AddUpdateButton"); }



    </div>
}
```

I'm sure it's something simple but I'm just not seeing it.

I was Missing JS on the View

```
  jQuery.validator.addMethod("requiredif", function (value, element, params) {
        if ($(element).val() != '') return true;

        var $other = $('#' + params.other);

        var otherVal = ($other.attr('type').toUpperCase() == "CHECKBOX") ?
            ($other.attr("checked") ? "true" : "false") : $other.val();

        return params.comp == 'isequalto' ? (otherVal != params.value)
            : (otherVal == params.value);
    });
    jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("requiredif", ["other"], function (options) {
        var $other = $('#' + "Object_IsActive");
        options.rules['required'] = "#" + "Object_IsActive" + (($other.attr('type').toUpperCase() == "CHECKBOX") ?
            ":checked" : ":filled");
        options.messages['required'] = options.message;
    });
```

Comment: Have you included the required js & css in view?

Comment: I Completely forgot to add the JS for that.... I knew it was a small oversight.